# Best Way to Map Flat Collection to Hierarchy

Tags: java, collections, mapping

My API needs to read large recordset and transform it an hierarchy (JSON) so that the UI (Angular) can display it appropriately. I am looking for an efficient way to achive this transformation (for 1000s of records).

**Which Collection type is best suited? Are there any preferred mappers?**

Details:

```
public class Batch implements Serializable {
    private Timestamp deliveryDateTime;
    private String deliveryLocation;
    private String patientName;
    // other batch details
}
```

I have a list of batches `Collection<Batch>`. When I return this collection to UI, it needs to be first sorted by deliveryDateTime, and then by deliveryLocation, and then by patientName.

The resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
    "deliveryDateTimes": [
        {
            "deliveryDateTime": "Mon, 20-Nov-2017",
            "deliveryLocations": [
                {
                    "deliveryLocation": "location1",
                    "patients": [
                        {
                            "patientName": "LastName1, FirstName1",
                            "batches": [
                                {
                                    "otherBatchDetails": "other batch details"
                                    // other batch details.
                                },
                                {
                                    "otherBatchDetails": "other batch details"
                                    // other batch details.
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is not a sort, that is a hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, how do I achieve it?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you intend to generate the JSON text, i.e. what library you want to use, and what features of that library you want to use. You probably want to create a class for each node in the hierarchy, and then map the `Batch` data into those nodes, then use a JSON library to serialize the object hierarchy to JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. I have tried and it works fine for me.

```
public class BatchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Batch> sortedList = generateBatches().stream().
                sorted(Comparator.comparing(Batch::getDeliveryDateTime).reversed().
                        thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Batch::getDeliveryLocation).
                        thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Batch::getPatientName)))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<Date, Map<String, Map<String, List<Batch>>>> result = sortedList.stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Batch::getDeliveryDateTime,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Batch::getDeliveryLocation,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(Batch::getPatientName,
                                        Collectors.toList()))));

        System.out.println("Batches : " + result);
    }

    private static List<Batch> generateBatches() {
        //DB call to fetch list of objects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A TreeSet collection can be used in this context. A comparator object for TreeMap is designed as follows:

```java
class BatchSorter implements Comparator<Batch>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Batch b1, Batch b2) {

        if(b1.getDeliveryDateTime().after(b2.getDeliveryDateTime())){
            return 1;
          } 
        else if(b1.getDeliveryDateTime().before(b2.getDeliveryDateTime())){
            return -1;
          }
        else{ // if 2 dates are equal
            if(b1.getDeliveryLocation().compareTo(b2.getDeliveryLocation())>0){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(b1.getDeliveryLocation().compareTo(b2.getDeliveryLocation())<0){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                return(b1.getPatientName().compareTo(b2.getPatientName())); // If location names are equal
            }

        }

     }
}
```

This can be used in TreeSet as follows:

```
TreeSet<Batch> ts = new TreeSet<Batch>(new BatchSorter());
```